# C# How do i add click event on context sub menu each dynamically

Tags: c#, contextmenu

Good day guys, i have a problem on creating submenu's click menu, normally i can cast it on each of their properties but my submenus are from database and i dont know how to add the click event hardcoded

my code so far

```
void loadTechnicianData()
        {
            TechnicianPanel.Controls.Clear();
            query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_technician`";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = constrings.GetDBConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Tech_UC uc = new Tech_UC();
                                uc.TechHeader.Text = reader["technician"].ToString();
                                uc.TechHeader.BackColor = Color.FromName(reader["color_assigned"].ToString());
                                uc.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["t_id"].ToString());
                                TechnicianPanel.Controls.Add(uc);

                                ToolStripMenuItem cm = startToolStripMenuItem as ToolStripMenuItem;
                                cm.DropDownItems.Add(reader["technician"].ToString());

                            //here i need to call a click event to call a method void outside the loop
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    CMessageBox m = new CMessageBox("error\n" + ex);
                    m.ShowDialog();
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cm.DropDownItems.Add(reader["technician"].ToString()).Click += MyMethod;
```

With:

```
void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

You can use a delegate or a lambda expression instead of a method if short and not reusable:

```
cm.DropDownItems.Add(reader["technician"].ToString()).Click += (_sender, _e) =>
{
  ...
};
```